# What's the benefit of the client-server model of memcached?

Tags: client-server, memcached

As I understand, the benefit of using memcached is to shorten the access time to the information stored in the database by caching it in the memory. But isn't the time overhead for the client-server model based on network protocol (e.g. TCP) also considerable as well? My guess is that it actually might be worse as network access is generally slower than hardware access. What am I getting wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's true that caching won't address network transport time. However, what matters to the user is the overall time from request to delivery. If this total time is perceptible, then your site does not seem responsive. Appropriate use of caching can improve responsiveness, even if your overall transport time is out of your control.

Also, caching can be used to reduce overall server load, which will essentially buy you more cycles. Consider the case of a query whose response is the same for all users - for example, imagine that you display some information about site activity or status every time a page is loaded, and this information does not depend on the identity of the user loading the page. Let's imagine also that this information does not change very rapidly. In this case, you might decide to recalculate the information every minute, or every five minutes, or every N page loads, or something of that nature, and always serve the cached version. In this case, you're getting two benefits. First, you've cut out a lot of repeated computation of values that you've decided don't really need to be recalculated, which takes some load off your servers. Second, you've ensured that users are always getting served from the cache rather than from computation, which might speed things up for them if the computation is expensive. 
Both of those could - in the right circumstances - lead to improved performance from the user's perspective. But of course, as with any optimization, you need to have benchmarks and actually benchmark to data rather than to your perceptions of what ought to be correct.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment. It's good to know that it also reduces the load on the server besides shortening the response time. To make sure I got it correctly, I guess the best practice in terms of the response time is to have the servers in close physical proximity as otherwise it could take up to 100ms for a packet to get across say, US.

Comment: You might want to look into the idea of the content delivery network. (CDN)